# i want to load text from a file and arrange the text 4 words on each line

Tags: python, python-3.9

i want to load text from a file and arrange  the text 4 words on each line

```
    with open(text_file, 'r') as f:
        size_to_read = 100
        lines = f.read(size_to_read)
        while len(lines) > 0:
            print(lines, end="")
            lines = f.read(size_to_read)
```

Comment: You need to be more clear about what the input format is, and why your existing code isn't doing the correct thing. Is it a word per line? A line of an arbitrary number of words? Something else?

Comment: Your code reads a text file 100 characters at a time and prints these characters until there is nothing left to read - what does that have to do with your problem? What have you tried yourself? Is there a reason you don't read the entire file at once (is that some requirement)? What constitutes a word, what does the input file look like?

Comment: I want load the txt file and rearrange the text in that, each line has only 4 strings or words till i get the whole text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can amend this to suit your code.

```
with open(text_file, 'r') as f:
        size_to_read = 100
        lines = f.read(size_to_read)
        for key, val in enumerate(lines.split(), start=1) :
           if key % 4== 0:
             print(val, end='\n')
           else:
             print(val, end= ' ')
```

Comment: thanks, but it gets each character, i want the each line to get 4 strings or words

Comment: yeah forgot to include the split

Comment: thank you... please how can i write it into another text file

Comment: use the open(file, 'a') as file: file.write(content)